# The cyclic analogue of the gonality of the superelliptic curve $s^n = t^m + 1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, galois-theory, galois-groups, kummer-theory

For naturals $n$, $m > 1$ consider the superelliptic curve $C\!: s^n = t^m + 1$, for simplicity, over an algebraically closed field of zero characteristic or large characteristic $p \nmid n$, $m$. I am especially interested in the case $n = 6$ and $m \leqslant 6$.

Let's define the cyclic analogue
$$
    \gamma_c := \min\{ \deg(\chi) \mid \chi\!: C \to \mathbb{P}^1 \textrm{ is a cyclic (i.e., Kummer) cover} \}
$$
of the gonality $\gamma$ of the curve $C$. Trivially, $\gamma \leqslant \gamma_c \leqslant \delta := \min\{n, m\}$. Under what conditions $\gamma_c = \delta$ and vice versa ? If this question is very difficult in general, I would be grateful for your answer at least in my particular case.